# Getting all music files

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get all music files of all the songs present on the phone. I am using mediastore to fetch all the songs title,artist etc. How should I fetch all music files ? 
Activity class:

```
public void getSongList() {
        //query external audio
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        //iterate over results if valid
        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong now? Do you get nothing in this cursor or an exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568798/list-all-music-in-mediastore-with-the-paths

Answer (score 3):

I am also having same problem just like you.Now I am solve This Problem just using following code.

```
   /**
 * It Not used AnyWhere in Project but it's Helpful while you need to get all mp3 file in sdcard.
 * it's nothing but just for future used
 *
 */
public void getAllSongs() {

    Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    String[] STAR=null;
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);
    //or
    //Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(allsongsuri, null, null, null, selection);




    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String song_name = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String Duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

                Log.e(TAG, "Song Name ::"+song_name+" Song Id :"+song_id+" fullpath ::"+fullpath+" Duration ::"+Duration);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();

    }
}
```

this Code is Working fine in My Application.In This Code we have just Print whole song path and it's name in Log.but you are too intelligent so you can change this code according to your Requirement.

I hope you are clear with my Idea.
**Best of Luck**

Comment: @mbelsky Please Check my Edit.

Comment: thanks you so much, i have problem, when i add music to dowload, it's not update music in my app. i use ContentResolver, it updated when i restart my genimation. can you have me when i add music to dowload, it will update in my app?