# play music file from file manager to my music player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I have developed one music player.i dont know how to play song from file manager to my app.i got my player name in open dialog of file manager.i dont know how to get song details and display it in my player with my format.pls anyone help.when i click my player name in open dialog of file manager its getting crashed.i dont know how to get data from file manager to my audio screen.i used below code only.

```
<activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.user.lmkplayer.Activities.AudioPlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get all your mp3 files with their artist names and duration and tiltle from file manager [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568798/list-all-music-in-mediastore-with-the-paths)